# validar autocompletar de ciudades

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5

tengo este código que autocompleta las ciudades de un país, lo hace perfecto, solo deseo validarlo, es decir que cuando escriben la ciudad en el input sea obligatorio elegir una del listado. Y NO escribir una personalizada, de antemano muchas gracias

```
<form name="ejemplo1" action="datos.php" method="POST">
        <div class="etiqueta">Ingrese paises: </div>
                <div class="input_container">
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="pais_id" name="paises" onkeyup="autocompletar()" >
                    <ul id="lista_id"></ul>
                </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Porque no cambias el input por un select.

Comment: El código está incompleto, falta el JavaScript.

Comment: Veo las opciones con input, pero son muchos datos, ciudades de todo el mundo y los obtengo mejor con un input y una base, ahora bien si lo hiciera con select, en que forma puedo resolver ese dilema, es decir que obligatoriamente elijan una opcion y no la escriban

Comment: basandome en tu respuesta alanfcm, hice un ejemplo con select y vaya que es sencillo, pero no logro validarlo y segui varios ejemplos, pero algo me falla en mi codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Si bien falta la parte de Js puedes hacerlo colocando una variable de estado, es decir creas una variable `let statusSelectCity = false` y cuando le hagas click a una ciudad del listado cambias esa variable a `true` luego validas en el submit del formulario que para enviarlo es necesario que la variable sea `true`

```
submitForm() {
   if (statusSelectCity) {
       // Enviamos el formulario
   } else {
       // Mensaje de error
   }
}
```

También puedes hacer esta validación en el blur de tu input para que cuando pierda el foco valide y te muestre el mensaje de inmediato.

Saludos!

Comment: mmm desconozco mucho de esta parte de la programacion.
no se ni los eventos en el momento que se cambie la variable, perdón, habrá algún ejemplo en linea, he buscado tanto que pruebo muchos muy sencillos, pero no logro validarlos o enviar sus datos mediante POST